# Deactivate SplashScreen after start

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When i start my application comes a SplashScreen for 3 seconds after that i am on my MainActivity when i press now the back button from my mobile im back on the SplashScreen. How can i adjust when i press the back button that, that close the app? 
I have programmed this

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK){
        if (!pressedOnce){
            pressedOnce = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erneut drücken,um zu beenden.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pressedOnce = false;

                }
            }, 3000);
        }else if (pressedOnce){
            pressedOnce = false;
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This is not the appropriate way to build a splash screen - you should use a [branded launch theme](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your MainActivity from the Splash screen with a flag and finish the splash Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: No problem, there are a whole plethora of Intent flags, and things such as taskAffinity - worth checking here first if you have similar issues : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

When you launch `Intent` to start your `MainActivity` write this.finish() to terminate `SplashScreen` activity and to remove it from your heap

Answer (score 0):

Put finish(); after the startActivity code where you start MainActivity in SplashScreen.class.